# Why does argparse not accept "--" as argument?

Tags: python, argparse

My script takes `-d`, `--delimiter` as argument:

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--delimiter')
```

but when I pass it `--` as delimiter, it is empty

```
script.py --delimiter='--'
```

I know `--` is special in argument/parameter parsing, but I am using it in the form `--option='--'` and quoted.

Why does it not work?
I am using Python 3.7.3

Here is test code:

```
#!/bin/python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--delimiter')
parser.add_argument('pattern')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.delimiter)
```

When I run it as `script --delimiter=-- AAA` it prints empty `args.delimiter`.

Comment: FWIW, you can simplify the example by putting the arguments in the script: `args = parser.parse_args('--delimiter=-- AAA'.split())`

Comment: The quotes don't matter; `--option=--` and `--option='--'` both become the exact same argv elements while the shell is parsing them (before Python is even started).

Comment: As you say it's special.  I'd have to look at the code to be sure, but I suspect it's being detected and removed earlier than you imagine.

Comment: BTW, this _does_ smell to me like unintended behavior. `--` should be special only completely on its own, as an exact match; `--delimiter=--` is not.

Comment: For me it's an empty list. Is that what you're getting, or is it an empty string? Try `print(args)` instead of `print(args.delimiter)`.

Comment: Somehow `args.delimiter` becomes a list instead of a string. It really shouldn't ever be anything but a string or None (with None being the value if you don't provide the option at all).

Comment: It works fine when you don't pass in `--` as the argument to `delimiter`.

Comment: Existing bug issue:  https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/58572  old, but patch still needs review and push.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This looks like a bug. You should report it.

[This code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/argparse.py#L2422-L2426) in `argparse.py` is the start of `_get_values`, one of the primary helper functions for parsing values:

```
if action.nargs not in [PARSER, REMAINDER]:
    try:
        arg_strings.remove('--')
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

The code receives the `--` argument as the single element of a list `['--']`. It tries to remove `'--'` from the list, because when using `--` as an end-of-options marker, the `'--'` string will end up in `arg_strings` for one of the `_get_values` calls. However, when `'--'` is the actual argument value, the code still removes it anyway, so `arg_strings` ends up being an empty list instead of a single-element list.

The code then goes through an else-if chain for handling different kinds of argument (branch bodies omitted to save space here):

```
# optional argument produces a default when not present
if not arg_strings and action.nargs == OPTIONAL:
    ...
# when nargs='*' on a positional, if there were no command-line
# args, use the default if it is anything other than None
elif (not arg_strings and action.nargs == ZERO_OR_MORE and
      not action.option_strings):
    ...
# single argument or optional argument produces a single value
elif len(arg_strings) == 1 and action.nargs in [None, OPTIONAL]:
    ...
# REMAINDER arguments convert all values, checking none
elif action.nargs == REMAINDER:
    ...
# PARSER arguments convert all values, but check only the first
elif action.nargs == PARSER:
    ...
# SUPPRESS argument does not put anything in the namespace
elif action.nargs == SUPPRESS:
    ...
# all other types of nargs produce a list
else:
    ...
```

This code should go through the 3rd branch,

```
# single argument or optional argument produces a single value
elif len(arg_strings) == 1 and action.nargs in [None, OPTIONAL]:
```

but because the argument is missing from `arg_strings`, `len(arg_strings)` is 0. It instead hits the final case, which is supposed to handle a completely different kind of argument. That branch ends up returning an empty list instead of the `'--'` string that should have been returned, which is why `args.delimiter` ends up being an empty list instead of a `'--'` string.

---

This bug manifests with positional arguments too. For example,

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('a')
parser.add_argument('b')

args = parser.parse_args(["--", "--", "--"])

print(args)
```

prints

```
Namespace(a='--', b=[])
```

because when `_get_values` handles the `b` argument, it receives `['--']` as `arg_strings` and removes the `'--'`. When handling the `a` argument, it receives `['--', '--']`, representing one end-of-options marker and one actual `--` argument value, and it successfully removes the end-of-options marker, but when handling `b`, it removes the actual argument value.

Comment: That begs the question, why is `'--'` in `arg_strings` in the first place? If it's acting as the optional argument terminator, shouldn't it be stripped out before that?

Comment: This was reported years ago, but not fixed, https://bugs.python.org/issue14364

Comment: @hpaulj nice find. From that link, it seems that the PR is ready, but it's just not merged yet.

Comment: The suggested patch hasn't been migrated to the github push format.  I don't recall if there were outstanding issues. `argparse` developers try to be cautious about anything that could have backward compatibliy issues.  I posted as `paul.j3`, but haven't done much after the github change.

Answer (score 8):

### Existing bug report

Patches have been suggested, but it hasn't been applied. [Argparse incorrectly handles '--' as argument to option](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/58572)

### Some simple examples:

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: a = p.add_argument('--foo')
In [4]: p.parse_args(['--foo=123'])
Out[4]: Namespace(foo='123')
```

The unexpected case:

```
In [5]: p.parse_args(['--foo=--'])
Out[5]: Namespace(foo=[])
```

Fully quote passes through - but I won't get into how you might achieve this via shell call:

```
In [6]: p.parse_args(['--foo="--"'])
Out[6]: Namespace(foo='"--"')
```

'--' as separate string:

```
In [7]: p.parse_args(['--foo','--'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo FOO]
ipython3: error: argument --foo: expected one argument
...
```

another example of the double quote:

```
In [8]: p.parse_args(['--foo','"--"'])
Out[8]: Namespace(foo='"--"')
```

In `_parse_known_args`, the input is scanned and classified as "O" or "A".  The '--' is handled as

```
        # all args after -- are non-options
        if arg_string == '--':
            arg_string_pattern_parts.append('-')
            for arg_string in arg_strings_iter:
                arg_string_pattern_parts.append('A')
```

I think the '--' are stripped out after that, but I haven't found that part of the code yet.   I'm also not finding were the '--foo=...' version is handled.

I vaguely recall some bug/issues over handling of multiple occurances of '--'.  With the migration to github, I'm not following `argparse` developements as much as I used to.

### edit

`get_values` starts with:

```
def _get_values(self, action, arg_strings):
    # for everything but PARSER, REMAINDER args, strip out first '--'
    if action.nargs not in [PARSER, REMAINDER]:
        try:
            arg_strings.remove('--')
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Why that results in a empty list will require more thought and testing.

The '=' is handled in `_parse_optional`, which is used during the first scan:

```
    # if the option string before the "=" is present, return the action
    if '=' in arg_string:
        option_string, explicit_arg = arg_string.split('=', 1)
        if option_string in self._option_string_actions:
            action = self._option_string_actions[option_string]
            return action, option_string, explicit_arg
```

### old bug issues

[argparse handling multiple "--" in args improperly](https://bugs.python.org/issue13922)

[argparse: Allow the use of -- to break out of nargs and into subparser](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/53780)

Comment: You could certainly pass _the literal string_ `"--"` from a shell (as by using `'--delimeter="--"'` or its exact equivalent `--delimeter='"--"'`), but if the string one intends to pass is `--`, I don't see how that serves the purpose. Quotes aren't special in this context -- one could just as well use `'%--%'` f/e, and it would be exactly as meaningful as `'"--"'` is.

Comment: Actually, the `arg_string` is the entire string `--delimiter=--` and it doesn't get skipped immediately. Try literring `print(namespace)` everywhere over the function, the `delimiter=[]` only happens on the `consume_optional` call.

Comment: `_parse_optional` splits the `--delimiter=--' into `(anAction, 'delimiter', '--').

Answer (score 4):

It calls `parse_args` which calls `parse_known_args` which calls `_parse_known_args`.

Then, on line 2078 (or something similar), it does this (inside a while loop going through the string):

```py
start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
```

which calls the `consume_optional` (which makes sense, because this is an optional argument it is parsing right now) defined earlier in the method `_parse_known_args`. When given `--delimiter='--'`, it will make this `action_tuples`:

```py
# if the action expect exactly one argument, we've
# successfully matched the option; exit the loop
elif arg_count == 1:
    stop = start_index + 1
    args = [explicit_arg]
    action_tuples.append((action, args, option_string))
    break

##
## The above code gives you the following:
##
action_tuples=[(_StoreAction(option_strings=['-d', '--delimiter'], dest='delimiter', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None), ['--'], '--delimiter')]
```

That is then iterated to, and is then fed to `take_action` on line 2009:

```py
assert action_tuples
for action, args, option_string in action_tuples:
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
    return stop
```

The `take_action` function will then call `self._get_values(action, argument_strings)` on line 1918, which, as mentioned in the answer by @hpaulj, removes the `--`. Then, you're left with the empty list.